# Reporting Services 2005 Deploying error: could not load file or assembly

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I made a report on Reporting Services 2005 which consumes an external assembly, I added that assembly to the project:

**Report - Report Properties - References**

I also copied the assembly to the folders:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

My report works fine it I hit F5, even on the Preview in Visual Studio Designer, but when I try to deploy the report (right click - Deploy) and point to a remote Reporting Services Server (http://myserver/reportserver) I got the error:

**Error 3 Error while loading code module: ‘XXXXXXXXXXXX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dc704fc78adc7af4’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'XXXXXXXX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dc704fc78adc7af4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. c:\MyReport\Report.rdl 0 0**

(NOTE: I replaced the name of the assembly with XXXXXXX and changed the path of my report. Consider that the file "c:\MyReport\Report.rdl" is already there, it's the report I'm working on).

Hope you can help me solve this problem to deploy to my remote reporting server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 3 days of headaches, I found out what I was doing wrong with the report deploy (This was my first time deploying a reporting services 2005 report).

If anyone else is interested: you need to copy the assembly to these folders **ON THE SERVER** (where you wish to deploy):

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

And that's it. Don't forget to change the data source of your report to use the correct credentials.

Comment: Thank you!  Note, on x64 bit systems, the folder will C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio XX.X\        .

Answer (score 0):

As I am not able to place any comment, I am putting my few doubts here.

Is the above process same as deployment in Sharepoint?

Are you mentioning the "TargetDataSource Folder", "TargetDataSet folder" and so on?

Will it work if I would copy the assembly file in below folder path of SharePoint Server:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Svices\ReportServer\bin
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual tudio 8\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies